# SQL Unprepare a PreparedStatement in node.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express

I'm using the node-mssql module (https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) and when I try to make a second request I got this error:

```
this.connection.pool.acquire(done);
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'acquire' of null at PreparedStatement._prepare
```

This is my code:

```
function verificarCodigoUsuario(config, req, query){
    var codigo = req.params.email.split("@", 1);
    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
        var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(connection);
        ps.input('codigo', sql.VarChar(100));
        ps.prepare(query, function(err) {
            ps.execute({codigo: codigo}, function(err, recordset){
                console.log(recordset);
            });
            ps.unprepare(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `unprepare` **after** `execute` has finished. Since the method is asynchronous, you need to add it inside the `execute` callback like they've done in the [example](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#preparedstatement).

```
function verificarCodigoUsuario(config, req, query) {
    var codigo = req.params.email.split("@", 1);
    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function (err) {
        var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(connection);
        ps.input('codigo', sql.VarChar(100));
        ps.prepare(query, function (err) {
            ps.execute({
                codigo: codigo
            }, function (err, recordset) {
                ps.unprepare(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
                console.log(recordset);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi, tks for your help, but the same error occurred.

Comment: The error only occurs when i use the res to responde the request do u know why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

this is my full code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var session = require('express-session');
var sql = require('mssql');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get("/cadastro/nome=:nome&email=:email&senha=:senha",function(req, res, next) {

        var sess = req.session;


        var config = {
        user: sess.cookie.user,
        password: sess.cookie.password,
        server: sess.cookie.server,
        database: sess.cookie.database};

        //Verificar codigo do usuário
        var queryConsulta =   'select cod_usuario_usu from [bd_iglu].[dbo].[tb_igl_usuario] where cod_usuario_usu = @codigo';
        verificarCodigoUsuario(config, req, queryConsulta);

       res.send("ok");

});


function verificarCodigoUsuario(config, req, query) {
    var codigo = req.params.email.split("@", 1);
    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function (err) {
        var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(connection);
        ps.input('codigo', sql.VarChar(100));
        ps.prepare(query, function (err) {
            ps.execute({
                codigo: codigo
            }, function (err, recordset) {
                ps.unprepare(function (err) {

                });
                console.log(recordset);
                return recordset;
            });
        });
    });
};

module.exports = router;
```